# iOSでのDrawerの実装について

Tags: ios, cocoapods, storyboard

iOSで作成中のアプリにDrawerを組込もうとしています。
下記のサンプルコードを下にして作ろうとしていました。
https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

現在、他の試作部分はstoryboardを用いて実装しているのですが、MMDrawerControllerはstoryboardを使わない実装のようです。

MMDrawerController-storyboardというものもあるのですが、これを落としてコンパイルしてみたところ下記のエラーになってしまいます。

```
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

本家を使ってsotryboard実装のviewとコード実のviewを混在させるか、MMDrawerController-storyboardの導入をがんばるかで迷っています。
アドバイスいただければうれしいです。

Answer (score 1):

cocoapodsをご存知でしょうか。
日本語の記事ですと、[iOSライブラリ管理の神ツール「CocoaPods」のインストールと使い方 (1/2)](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1403/08/news008.html)あたりが詳しいかなと思います。本家は[CocoaPods Guides](http://guides.cocoapods.org/)です。

cocoapodsのインストールと利用できる環境を整えるのは、上記記事を参考にしていただければと思いますが、
[Storyboard category extension for MMDrawerController](https://github.com/TomSwift/MMDrawerController-Storyboard)にもpodspecがありcocoapodsに登録されていますので、

```
pod 'MMDrawerController+Storyboard'
```

とすれば利用できます。なお、dependencyにMMDrawerControllerが入っていますので、プロジェクトにMMDrawerControllerを直接、追加している場合は削除したほうがいいと思います。

リンクのみで恐縮ですが、[Side Drawer Navigation for iOS](http://pulkitgoyal.in/side-drawer-navigation-for-ios/)に自力でStoryBoard上でMMDrawerControllerを使う例があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。　pod 'MMDrawerController+Storyboard'までは大丈夫でした。次のリンクについて、MMDrawerController本体＋Storyboardを使う方法のようですが、'MMDrawerController+Storyboard'を導入した場合も同様の実装で良いのでしょうか？